# How do I iterate a range of values?

Tags: ruby, iterator, range

I understand that:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.each { |x| puts x } #=> 1,2,3,4,5
```

How do I get the same to read for an inclusive range?

When I put:

```
array = [1...5]
array.each { |x| puts x }
```

I just get `1...5`. I really want: `1,2,3,4,5`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`1..5` and `1...5` are both examples of Ruby [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html) literals. `[1...5]` is an array with one element, a `Range`. You can create an `Array` from a `Range` with the `.to_a` method, as in `(1..5).to_a`

The parentheses around the range are important because of the relatively low precedence of the `..` symbol.

`Range` values are also directly enumerable, like arrays, as in `(1..5).each {|x| puts x}`

Comment: Ahhh, that clarifies it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

coding as follows:

```
(1..5).each { |x| puts x }
```